# Sumar array en Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Necesito saber la forma de poder sumar array en el componente de Angular (TypeScript)

```
addCostCenter(i){
    this.costCenter.push(i);
  }
```

Cada vez que doy click, va a haber una función que me va a añadir un array; tendré muchos array unidimensionales.

Necesito saber la forma en la que pueda sumar todos los array que hay dentro y que si la suma da más de 100, aparezca un error; o si da menos de 100, un error. La suma de todos los array que agregue, debe de ser de 100.

En conclusión; quiero saber cómo se pueden sumar los array y cómo hacer para que diga que la suma debe de ser 100. Si es mas o menos de 100; me salga error.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega una variable booleana para indicar **cuándo se debe mostrar** el mensaje de error usando [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

#### Ejemplo

---

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-costcenter',
  templateUrl: './nombre.component.html',
})
export class TuComponent {
  private showError: boolean = false;
  private constCenter: Array<any> = [];

  public addCostCenter(i): void {
    this.costCenter.push(i);
    if (this.sumCosts() > 100) {
      this.showError = true;
    }
  }

  public sumCosts(): number {
    return this.costCenter.reduce((acc, val) => (
      acc + val.reduce((accx, valx) => accx + valx, 0)
    ), 0);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<section>
  <button (click)="addCostCenter(10)">Add cost center</button>
  <div className="error" *ngIf="showError">You has been passed of 100 units</div>
</section>
```